# 12 hours and still cant upgrade to BIND 9.8.2 from 9.7.0

Tags: ubuntu, bind

My main objective to to get to install Samba4.  But the hangups are ridiculous at this point.  Samba 4 is telling me to install BIND 9.8+ So after figuring out the right ./configure I do a make install & now get

```
named -V
BIND 9.8.1-P1 built with '--with-openssl=/usr' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind'
    using OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
```

Yay , a start - but my daemon that still runs in my /etc/init.d/bind9 is still the 9.7.0 version.  I've tried restarting. `make distclean` & starting again.  I've checked my logs and I still get

```
    Jan 25 23:50:54 hoosier named[25320]: built with '--prefix=/usr' '--mandir=/usr
/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--sysconfdir=/etc/bind' '--localstatedir=/var' 
'--enable-threads' '--enable-largefile' '--with-libtool' '--enable-shared' '--enable-
static' '--with-openssl=/usr' '--with-gssapi=/usr' '--with-gnu-ld' '--with-
dlz-postgres=no' '--with-dlz-mysql=no' '--with-dlz-bdb=yes' '--with-dlz-filesystem=yes' 
'--with-dlz-ldap=yes' '--with-dlz-stub=yes' '--with-geoip=/usr' '--enable-ipv6' 
'CFLAGS=-fno-strict-aliasing -DDIG_SIGCHASE -O2' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions' 
'CPPFLAGS='
```

I've attempted to repeat that line in my ./configure for the 9.8 version, but then I get errors: @ the gssapi line that it can't find the file; that the -DDIG_SIGCHASE argument isn't recognized; and DLZ isn't on my system.

So my main question is, how do I get the bind9(.7.0) daemon to release control? and grant it to 9.8.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the one that was installed by the `bind9` Ubuntu package.  Did you replace the `named` instance binary that the package installed?

Run `which named` - if it's not pointing to `/usr/sbin/named`, then the version that the Ubuntu package installed is still there.  Replace it or point the init script at the right path for your newly compiled version.

But let's back up a sec - how'd you get down this rabbit hole in the first place?  What's wrong with `apt-get install samba4`, or if that's not new enough, using the [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~samba-team/+archive/ppa) (`add-apt-repository ppa:samba-team/ppa`)?

Comment: I installed this ubuntu + bind ~ 2 years ago.  Not doubting its the original package.

Comment: (whoops continued...)  Not doubting its the original package.   'root@hoosier:/etc/bind# which named
/usr/local/sbin/named'   was my response on that.  I just don't know where to change the pointer/ init script.
apt-get install samba4 worked just fine, but it was around step 6 from [http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/HOWTO#Step_10_Configure_kerberos_DNS_dynamic_updates_.28optional.29] that told me to get Bind 9.8+

Comment: @Kamikaze478 Modify the file `/etc/init.d/bind9`, the `/usr/sbin/named` path will be in there, and will need to be changed to your newly compiled copy in `/usr/local/sbin/`.

Comment: Thank you. I had about 4 paths listed under #path I just deleted /bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin options altogether.  There were 2 command line instances that I needed to modify as well. I was digging myself a hole so deep I was getting "rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused" errors and was starting to "chown root:bind" certain directories. Cause I was unable to restart BIND for about 4 hours. I do get an peculiar message when I restart bind9 though: `/etc/init.d/bind9: 130: awk: not found
/etc/init.d/bind9: 130: pgrep: not found
[ OK ]`   ...but it works.

Comment: You do *not* want to remove those directories from your path variable.  The cure will be a lot worse than the disease.  If anything, `mv /usr/sbin/named /usr/sbin/named-9.7`.